# git ls-tree output of working directory?

Tags: git, git-ls-tree

I am looking for a way to have output in the same manner as `ls-tree`, but of my working directory. Whenever I run `git ls-tree .` it says `fatal: Not a valid object name .`

Comment: `git ls-files` probably with `-m`?

Comment: git ls-tree -r HEAD

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`git ls-tree` only works with git refs, e.g. `ls-tree HEAD` or `ls-tree 1.9.1`

Try `git ls-files`.  You probably want the `-s` and/or `-m` flags.

---

As you point out, `git ls-files -s` will list the files in the index (i.e. files that have been staged).

In theory, you could mess with the index, run `git ls-files -s`, then try restore it, e.g.

```
git commit
git add .
git ls-files -s
git reset .
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Seems right, and worked in a simple test, but could eat all your files.

Comment: Thank you. I think that properly speaking, what I asked is impossible. The reason is that there is no hashed object for files in the working directory. For the _index_, however, there are of course hashed objects as you pointed out by suggesting the `-s` flag. This isn't exactly the same output, but I don't want to bother remaking the functionality of other git commands. :)

Comment: It seems `-m` doesn't have the desired effect, as you imply.  I had a go a listing the working directory rather than the index.  See updated answer.  And test before doing it on your real data. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to @mikel's answer, but uses `git stash create` and `ls-tree`, as requested by the OP.
Also avoids using `git reset`, which is more likely to break things for the inexperienced user.

This however only works for tracked files.

```sh
git ls-tree `git diff --quiet && echo HEAD || git stash create ls-tree`
```

This will leave a [dangling commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-create), which will should eventually be removed by `git gc`.
(Actually [two dangling commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218432/1012586).)
Of course you could search for dangling commits containing `ls-tree`, but I haven't found a simple way to do so (at least not without quite a bit of `sed` and `grep` magic - suggestions welcome ).

**Explanation**

`git ls-tree` needs a hash. If the tree is clean (`git diff --quiet` returns `0`) one can use `HEAD`. If it isn't, `git stash create` will create a commit and return it's hash.

**Untracked**

Unfortunately `git stash create` does not support `-a`/`-u` or other flags. Thus it's not possible to show the hashes of untracked files. Getting their information is a bit more complicated:

```
git stash -a
git ls-tree stash
git ls-tree stash^3
git stash pop
```

This will first show tracked files (`git ls-tree stash`) and then untracked files (`git ls-tree stash^3`).
[torek provides a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218432/1012586) why `stash^3` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to find something which is not touching the git repo.

This one is not git only and depends on linux like 'grep'

```
#from root of repo dir
git ls-tree -r HEAD 
#other dirs
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep <relative_path_to_repo_root>/
# eg
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep src/
```

Also found following (git only) working in subdirectories of repo root

```
git ls-tree -r --full-name HEAD
```

However man page (man git-ls-tree) is irritating git logic

```
   --full-name
       Instead of showing the path names relative to the current working directory, show the full path names.

   --full-tree
       Do not limit the listing to the current working directory. Implies --full-name.
```