# How to see untracked files in Git stashes

Tags: git

I regularly stash work that I've done in new (untracked) files, and I expect to be able to find this work later.  The obvious way to find it seems to be `git show`.

I just discovered that Git completely omits these files when I use `git show` (but fortunately does not overlook them when popping stashed code), making it seemingly impossible to reliably find stashed code.

To make this more concrete, suppose I have

```
On branch feature/request-reappointment
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   app/models/job.rb
    modified:   config/initializers/environmental_email_interceptor.rb

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    app/models/receipt.rb
    db/migrate/20200130091050_create_receipts.rb

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I perform

```
git stash save -u 'miscellaneous improvements'
git show stash@{0}
```

Git will omit the untracked files.  Not only is this the behavior of Git from the command line, but GUI tools like Fork and GitKraken have the same problem, presumably inherited from Git.

How can I show the *actual* contents of the stash, *including* the untracked files?

UPDATE:

although GitKraken and Fork failed to show the untracked files in any stashes, Tower 2 (an old version, since I refused to switch to their subscription-based pricing model) *succeeded*.  I have to give them some credit, and if not for the price I'd buy a new copy today.

Comment: If you have a look at the stashed commit, it should look like a three-parent merge commit. The diffs for the untracked files should be in the third parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

To see the file names, use `git ls-tree -r stash^3`; to see their contents, use `git show stash^3`.

#### Long

> How can I show the *actual* contents of the stash, *including* the untracked files?

The untracked files *usually aren't in the stash*.  There is an exception—and you're using it, so I'll get to that in a moment.  But showing those files is tricky.  Using them is even harder.  The `git stash` front end needs some work here, in my opinion.

First, though, it's important to understand how Git works internally.  A Git *repository* is primarily a pair of databases.  One—the biggest one, almost always—holds *commits* and other Git objects.  A smaller database holds *names:* branch names like `master`, tag names like `v2.1`, remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, and so on.  Branch names and tag names and the like are specific forms of the general purpose *ref* or *reference*.  A ref holds a single Git hash ID, most commonly a commit hash ID.<sup>1</sup>

Each commit itself can also hold one or more previous-commit hash IDs.  These are the *parents* of the commit.  For normal (non-stash) commits, these usually form a nice simple chain: the last commit remembers, as its parent, the second-to-last.  That second-to-last commit remembers *its* parent—the last commit's grandparent—and the grandparent remembers another parent and so on.  A commit with two parents is a merge commit, by definition.

So, a branch name simply holds the hash ID of the commit we'd like to say is the last commit in / on / of that branch.  Multiple names can select the same hash ID, and/or a hash ID can be *reachable* from some branch by starting at its tip commit and working backwards.  So commits, in Git, are often on more than one branch.

The commits themselves contain snapshots of all of your (tracked) files.  Git makes them by writing the tracked files into Git's *index* and then using `git write-tree`, which writes the files into internal tree objects, followed by `git commit-tree`, which writes a commit object using the tree(s) written by `git write-tree`.  So all commits have their origin in the index.  And, any file in the index is tracked, by definition.  So this gets us to a bit of a puzzle.

---

<sup>1</sup>Branch names and remote-tracking names are *required* to hold *only* commit hash IDs; tag names are more flexible.

---

#### The stash

The special ref `refs/stash`, if it exists, points to one commit.  That is the `stash@{0}` commit.  (Its reflog entries in `stash@{1}` on up also point to one commit each.)  So the stash, when it exists, consists of commits.  These commits are on *no* branch:<sup>2</sup> they're found through `refs/stash` instead.

A normal stash has the *form* of a merge commit, but not the same substance.  What `git stash` does is to make two commits, using the very low-level `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree` method described above.  The first such commit, based on whatever is in your index when you run `git stash save` or `git stash push`, is easy: `git write-tree` already just writes whatever is in the index, so the two commands, put together, make this index commit, which I call `i` (and the `git stash` documentation calls `I`).

The second commit is trickier, but essentially, what `git stash` does is run `git add -u` (though without actually using `git add -u` and thereby introducing bugs in various versions of `git stash`, some of which in some cases produce the wrong work-tree commit).  This updates the index so that it holds all tracked files as of their state in the work-tree.  Then `git write-tree` followed by `git commit-tree` makes a good snapshot of your work-tree, minus of course any untracked files.

Because `git stash` is using the low-level commands, it can make the work-tree commit—I call it `w`—with any set of parents it chooses.  It makes this commit with both `i` and `HEAD` as its two parents:

```
...--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
        |\
        i-w
```

The `i` commit looks like any ordinary commit, and the `w` commit resembles a merge.  It's not actually a merge—it's just a snapshot of your work-tree, as added to the index—but it has as its first parent the tip commit of your current branch, and as its second parent, commit `i`.

After making this stash, `git stash save` does a `git reset --hard`, so that your index and work-tree match `HEAD`.  The `HEAD` itself never moves, and untracked files weren't saved and are unaffected.

When you do a `git stash save -u` or `git stash save -a`, however, Git makes a *third* commit, which I call `u`.  This *third* commit uses an index that is cleared of all *tracked* files, and is then loaded with some or all of your *untracked* files, as if by `git add --force` on specific file names.<sup>3</sup>  The set of files that go into this third commit depends on whether you used `-u` or `-a`: `-u` enumerates untracked files that are *not* ignored, and `-a` enumerates all untracked files, even if they *are* ignored.  Git copies those files into the (well, an) index and makes this `u` commit, with no parent at all, *before* it makes the final `w` commit.  Then it makes the `w` commit with `u` as its third parent:

```
...--o--o   <-- branch (HEAD)
        |\
        i-w
         /
        u
```

Thus, `w^1` is the commit at the tip of the branch, `w^2` is the index commit `i`, and `w^3` is the `u` commit.  `w` continues to resemble a merge commit—this time, an octopus merge—but its snapshot is the same as for any two-commit stash.

Having made a `u` commit, `git stash save` or `git stash push` now *removes* from your work-tree all of the files that are in the `u` commit.  If some files in `u` are also ignored, they're still removed.

Applying a three-commit stash fails if Git cannot extract the `u` commit into your current work-tree.  So it's definitely useful to know what is in this third `u` commit.  But there's no `git stash ____` (fill in the blank with a verb) to show whether commit `u` even exists, much less what is in it.  We must therefore fall back on lower-level Git commands.

In particular, since `u` is a *root commit*, `git show` will diff it against the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).  You can use `git show --name-only` or `git ls-tree -r` to get the list of files, if you don't want a full diff.  To *name* commit `u`, we can name any stash commit—any of the `w` commit objects pointed to by `refs/stash` or one of the reflog entries for it—and add the `^3` suffix to mean *third parent*.  If the stash has only `w` and `i`, the `^3` will fail: there is no third parent, and hence nothing to show.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can, if you like, actually get them onto a branch, but the result is ... ugly at best.

<sup>3</sup>Internally, `git stash` uses a temporary index instead of the real / main index, to make this easier.  It does that for the `w` commit too.  While there is one special index, *the* index, that tracks your work-tree, you can create a temporary index at any time, put its path name into `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, and use Git commands with that temporary index instead of using the distinguished index.  That's handy for any command that needs to create a commit—which requires using the index—that doesn't want to disturb the index in the process.

Comment: `git show stash^3` displays the names and contents of the files but `git ls-files stash^3` doesn't show anything

Comment: @iconoclast: oops, that should have been `git ls-tree` (with `-r` to visit subtrees); will fix.