# Can git ls-tree list the index?

Tags: git

I created a new sub-directory and created a new file in it. I then `add`ed all to the Staging Area. `git ls-files -s` shows the new file, but does not show the tree that represents the sub-directory.

Is there a way to show the contents of the Staging Area using `git ls-tree`? Is there a ref pointing to the index?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082514/git-ls-tree-output-of-working-directory is similar, but specifically about the contents of the working directory

Comment: I've read somewhere that for some reason git doesn't create a `tree` object of the index (which is unfortunate and would imply the answer to your "can we" question is no).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The index itself doesn't contain trees,<sup>1</sup> and file names as stored *in* the index are full path names (with forward slashes, even if your host OS uses backward slashes).  The `git ls-tree` command reads tree entries (only), not the index; the `git ls-files` command reads the index;<sup>2</sup> and [never the twain shall meet](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/never+the+twain+shall+meet).

---

<sup>1</sup>Except, that is, for an *extension* that can cache a tree object seen earlier.  This is meant to speed up a future `git commit`.

<sup>2</sup>The `git ls-files` command also needs, sometimes, to read the *working tree*.  Confusingly, the term *working tree* has nothing at all to do with Git's internal *tree objects*.  The term "working tree" encompasses an OS-provided entity, where the OS allows Git to store the de-compressed, un-Git-ified files *extracted from* a commit.  The extraction process consists of reading a commit to find a tree object—the top level tree that stores the snapshot that goes with the commit—and then reading that tree and, recursively, any sub-trees to which that tree refers.  These provide the path name *components*, such as `path`, `to`, and `file`, which the recursive-reading process joins up into a simple string, `path/to/file`.  That simple string winds up in Git's *index* aka *staging area* aka *cache;* Git then uses the string—in cooperation with the OS, which might demand backwards slashes<sup>3</sup>—to create or delete or update folders and files-within-folders as necessary.

<sup>3</sup>Fortunately, even on Windows, the underlying OS allows forward slashes in path-names.  (I don't know whether various Git-for-Windows versions make use of this.)  In any case, Git itself is constantly having to analyze paths and handle the inevitable "D-F conflicts" that occur: commit `badf00d` might have a *file* named `path/a`, while commit `deadcab` has a *file* named `path/a/b`.  Between the two, `path/a` has a D-F conflict: it needs to be a directory (sometimes) and a file (sometimes).

Personally, I think it might be interesting to have an OS in which `path/to` can be opened and used as a file while, at the same time, having `path/to/file` available as a path name *for* a file.  The OS's equivalent of `lstat` would need to be able to tell you that `path/to` is *both* directory *and* file, whenever there are files visible underneath `path/to`.  But all the systems on which Git runs dictate that `path/to` can only be *one* of these.